# WebRtc peerConnection failed while setting local description

Tags: webrtc, peer-connection

While setting localdescription on sending offer to peer i'm facing such as error:

```
"Failed to set local offer sdp: Session error code: ERROR_CONTENT.
```

Session error description:

```
Failed to set local video description recv parameters"
```

It occurs in Chrome only rather than in Firefox where there is nothing in console. Obviously the connection between peers is not established.
I just want to update an audio sectin with following settings:

```
m=audio 54312 RTP/AVP 101 a=rtpmap:101 opus/48000/2 a=fmtp:101 stereo=1; 
sprop-stereo=1
```

Therefore look for m=audio and replace payload values only. There is nothing to do with video which retains as it is.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Actually it doesn't work on setRemoteDescription while signaling server routed the adjusted sdp

Comment: Did you find any hack/solution for this? It happens to me when I'm trying to create an offer invoked by `onnegotiationneeded` after adding video track (having audio already). From chrome 67 to firefox 61.

Comment: Same thing happening with me, from chrome to firefox while adding a new track. Any solution anyone? Any thoughts if adapter.js might solve this?

Comment: Same problem here. Any help here?